# Синонимизировать метки на тему [ос]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть три метки на тему операционных систем:

- [os](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os) (280 вопросов)
- [ос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%81) (130 вопросов)
- [операционные-системы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b) (1 вопрос)

Надо их синонимизировать.

С меткой [os](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os) есть такая проблема: её используют в вопросах про модуль os из стандартной библиотеки Python'а. Можно сделать также, как и с [keyboard](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard), который одновременно и [клавиатура](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0), и Python'овский модуль: там создана метка [python-keyboard](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-keyboard) именно для обозначения модуля. Итак, я предлагаю:

1. создать метку [python-os](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-os),
2. повесить её на все вопросы про модуль `os`, и убрать с них метку [os](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os) (их не очень-то много)
3. синонимизировать

Comment: Не уверен, что множественное число в метке уместно в данном случае.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, синонимизируйте так, как считаете нужным. Но с меткой [tag:os] есть одна проблема, о которой я [дописал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/12879/2) в вопросе.

Comment: Создать новую метку и добавить её на необходимые вопросы можно и без модератора. С объединением меток же есть нюанс, [выясняю](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391836/339911) как будет оптимальнее.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, насчет добавления метки, я не прошу, чтобы вы это сделали, я спрашиваю, надо ли это делать.

Comment: Если есть желание сделать, то почему бы нет? Мне кажется, об этом даже не нужно кого-то спрашивать. Если ещё и описание предложить, то вообще шикарно.

Comment: "не очень-то много" - всего-то 131.