# Метки вида [язык-библиотека] для избежания путаницы - стоит ли так делать?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Недавно я [писал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12879/507426) про синонимизацию метки [os](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os) и нашёл такую проблему: эту метку используют как для обозначения операционной системы, так и модуля *os* из стандартной библиотеки Python'а. Есть ещё метки с похожей же проблемой:

- [sys](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sys) - модуль *sys*, или *система*
- [operator](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator) - модуль *operator*, или *оператор*
- [multiprocessing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiprocessing) - модуль *multiprocessing* и *мултипроцессность*
- и т. п. ...

Я предлагаю сделать так, как уже сделано с меткой [keyboard](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard), которая и модуль *keyboard*, и *клавиатура* - там создана метка [python-keyboard](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-keyboard) для обозначения непосредственно модуля, а метка [keyboard](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) синонимизирована с [клавиатура](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0).

Итак, что я предлагаю делать, например для [os](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os):

- создать метку [python-os](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-os)
- привести в порядок вопросы с меткой [os](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os) - там, где имеется в виду Python'овский модуль - повесить [python-os](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-os), а где операционная система - оставить
- синонимизировать метку [os](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os) (теперь там только операционная система) с [ос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%81) или что-то в этом роде

Аналогично и с [sys](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sys), [operator](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operator) и т. п.

PS: на "большом" SO так делают - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-multiprocessing) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-unittest) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-datetime)

Answer (score 3):

В принципе метки вида "язык-библиотека" имеет смысл создавать, например, чтобы не путать метки для абстрактных понятий и метки библиотек.

Например, условный `uninttest` - это про модульное тестирование или про соответствующий модуль в Python? Кстати, [python-unittest](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-unittest) пришлось создать после того, как [unittest](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unittest) [синонимизировали c юнит-тестами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1321/1365).

Или тот же [keyboard](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) - это клавиатура вообще или модуль?

---

По поводу конкретных названных меток, мое мнение:

Для стандартных модулей `os` и `sys` (я думаю) отдельные метки не нужны вообще, т.к. набор функций в этих модулях довольно разнородный, и вопросы обычно по конкретным функциям, а не по самим модулям. Как вариант, можно заменить тот же `os` на что-то более конкретное, типа [os-system](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-system) (`os.system()`) или [os-listdir](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-listdir) (`os.listdir()`). С другой стороны, я не сторонник того, чтобы на каждую функцию заводилась отдельная метка, но в принципе, для популярных функций возможно в этом есть смысл.

`operator` - сам модуль более-менее тематический, но по этой метке из 5 вопросов ([`[python] [operator] is:q`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boperator%5D+%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aq)) ровно 2 вопроса конкретно по этому модулю. Так что не очень много смысла в отдельной метке. Я бы сказал, что тут можно просто синонимизировать с [операторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b), и не париться.

`multiprocessing` - думаю, имеет смысл в отдельной метке [python-multiprocessing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-multiprocessing), т.к. метка максимально тематическая, вопросы и по модулю, и про сам механизм мультипроцессинга в Python, и очевидно нужна отдельная метка для Python, чтобы не путать с мультипроцессингом вообще.