# Метки [мультипроцессность] и [multiprocessing]

Tags: предложение, метки, удаление-метки

Есть метки [multiprocessing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiprocessing) - 241 вопрос и [мультипроцессность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c) - 1 вопрос (они, очевидно, дубликаты). Даже не знаю, что с ними делать, но склоняюсь к той версии, что последнюю надо просто удалить - для синонима слишком мало вопросов.

Comment: Не очевидно. multiprocessing - это модуль Python, и большинство вопросов по этой метке касаются именно его, и только [24](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiprocessing+-python+-python-3.x) - мультипроцессорности в других языках или вообще. Перед слиянием нужно сначала перенести на отдельную метку вопросы касающиеся конкретно мультипроцессорности в Python.

Comment: См. обсуждение здесь: [Метки вида язык-библиотека для избежания путаницы - стоит ли так делать?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12880/1365)

Comment: Проще наверное вручную поменять метку в этих 24 вопросах, в остальных, если это возможно (если у модераторов есть такие инструменты) - массово поменять метку на [tag:python-multiprocessing]. После этого можно будет синонимизировать.

Comment: * мультипроцессности, не мультипроцессорности