# Надо синонимизировать метки на тему [adsense]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Надо синонимизировать метки:

- [adsense](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adsense) (25 вопросов)
- [google-adsense](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-adsense) (10 вопросов)

Я конечно понимаю, что я и сам смогу их вырезать где надо, но хочется чтобы новые вопросы с этой меткой сразу изменялись.

Итак предлагаю синонимизировать эти метки в сторону [google-adsense](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-adsense) (более понятное название).

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12880/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c

Comment: @Зонтик А почему он связанный?

Comment: Не дубликат, а именно связанный. Кинул ссылку, чтобы ни у кого не было сомнений, что гланая метка именно [tag:google-adsense].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 31 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 25 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 19 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'adsense': [adsense] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 29
tag remapping of [google-adsense] and [adsense] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym adsense -> google-adsense was approved!
```