# Надо синонимизировать метки [system] и [система]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Метки

- [система](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0) (31 вопрос)
- [system](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system) (75 вопросов)

надо синонимизировать. Основная - [система](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0) (она на русском).

Comment: Не очень понятно о чём эта метка. Также рекомендую обратить внимание на [вопрос по синонимизации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12968/176217).

Comment: @Зонтик И ещё метод `system` модуля `os` в Python.

Comment: @Зонтик, *...отделить вопросы про класс System...* - что значит *отделить*? убрать с них эту метку? заменить её на какую-то другую? или что-то ещё?

Comment: @wchistow либо вообще убрать с них метку, либо создать более конкретные метки и заменить на них.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Синонимизировать не надо. Надо разобрать беспорядок.

- Для вопросов про операционные системы есть метка [ос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%81) с [неоформленными синонимами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12879/%d0%a1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%81), либо метки [windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows), [linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) и так далее.
- Для вопросов про файловую систему есть отдельная метка ([файловая-система](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0)).
- Для вопросов про класс `System` в разных языках можно создать отдельные метки для каждого языка, либо оставить [system](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system), но добавить описание. Пока создал [java.lang.system](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.lang.system). Предложил несколько правок вопросов с метками [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)[system](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system) с заменой [system](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system) на [java.lang.system](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.lang.system) (но правки улучшали и тела вопросов!).

**Обновление:**

Метки [system](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system) и [система](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0) сняты со всех вопросов и заменены более подходящими. Спасибо [клубу редакторов ruSO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148414/ruso)!